# AngularJS: Error with chunking iterator

Tags: angularjs

I am receiving many of these in my browser console:

> error within chunking iterator: TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of
>   null

My application currently consists of a list of locations and map display, and when clicking on a location the map is zoomed to that lat\lon.

After a handful of clicks, I start getting this error and the map no longer responds.

I am using the angular-google-maps directive if that has any bearing on the answer too.

My map is coded up like so:

```
<div ng-controller="MapController as mapCtrl" class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-4 col-md-9 col-md-offset-3 main">
                <ui-gmap-google-map center='mapCtrl.map.center' zoom='mapCtrl.map.zoom'>
                    <ui-gmap-markers models="mapCtrl.mapMarkers" coords="'self'" icon="'icon'" options="'options'">
                    </ui-gmap-markers>
                </ui-gmap-google-map>

            </div>
```

In my MapController:

```
app.controller('MapController', ['$scope', 'LastReportedEventStore', 'MapMarkerService', 'uiGmapGoogleMapApi', function ($scope, LastReportedEventStore, MapMarkerService, uiGmapGoogleMapApi) {

    var self = this;
    //Default to UK overview
    self.map = { center: { latitude: 51.63841, longitude: -0.55494 }, zoom: 7 };

    uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function (maps) {
        self.mapMarkers = MapMarkerService.transformResponseData(LastReportedEventStore.lastReportedEvents);

    });

    $scope.$on('zoomtolatlon', function (event, args) {
        self.map = { center: { latitude: args.lat, longitude: args.lon }, zoom: 15 };
    });



} ]);
```

I have a separate controller for my locations list, so that when a click happens on one of the elements, I handle through ng-click in a function and broadcast an event:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('zoomtolatlon', { lat: lat, lon: lon });
```

Can anyone shed light on what seems to be causing this to fall over?

**EDIT**

OK, so I should have posted some more code on what I am doing here. I have a service as follows:

```
app.factory('DataStoreService', function ($rootScope, $location, $http, $timeout, LastReportedEventStore, MapMarkerService) {

    var getLastReportedEventsURL = '/location/GetLastReportedEvents.json?FieldSet=1&modifiedSince=0';

    //TO-DO: Need to think about adding a cachebuster _dc param like we do in ExtJS?

    return {

        //lastReportedEvents: lastReportedEvents,
        getLastReportedEvents: function () {
            $http.get(getLastReportedEventsURL)
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                    if (data.success) {

                        var result = angular.fromJson(data);
                        getLastReportedEventsURL = 'location' + result.nextURL;
                        LastReportedEventStore.transformResponseData(result.data);
                        if (angular.isDefined(google)) {
                            MapMarkerService.transformResponseData(result.data);
                        }
                        $rootScope.$emit('lastreportedeventsreceived');


                    }
                    else {
                        console.log('getLocationData ERROR!');
                    }
                })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log('getLocationData ERROR!');
                });

        }

    };

});
```

My main module

```
var app = angular.module('ppMobi', [])
.run(['DataStoreService', '$timeout', '$rootScope', function (DataStoreService, $timeout, $rootScope) {

    DataStoreService.getLastReportedEvents();

    $rootScope.$on('lastreportedeventsreceived', function (event) {
        $timeout(function () {
            DataStoreService.getLastReportedEvents();
        }, 5000);
    });

}]);
```

So when the application is bootstrapped, a $http.get() is performed immediately and then from the success handler in that request in the service, an event is raised that $rootScope handles in the run block as above. It's when the timeout occurs and the new fetch is performed that I am seeing the chunking iterator error

Comment: attach fiddle please

Comment: Did you ever manage to figure out the issue?